# Executar uma ação quando o botão 'Aceito' for pressionado

Tags: ionic

Pessoal estou fazendo um App no Ionic e quando o usuário aperta o botão Sair eu consegui configurar uma mensagem de Alert, mas como eu configuro o botão "Aceito" do PopUp do Alert ?
Eu quero que o usuário seja redirecionado para a HomePage.
Quando o botão está lá no html eu sei fazer, mas no Alert não faço idéia, já olhei documentação e nada.[image: Esta é a imagem do App]

Meu botão no .html

```
<button class="p4" ion-item (click)="showConfirm()"><img class="img4" 
src="../../assets/imgs/logout.png">Sair</button>
```

Meu botão no .ts

```
function showConfirm() {
    const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Deseja Realmente Sair ?',
        message: 'Você será redirecionado para a PáginaPrincipal',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Não Aceito',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Disagree clicked');
                }
            },
            {
               text: 'Aceito',
               handler: () => {
                  console.log('Agree clicked');
               }
           }
       ]
  });
  confirm.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa incluir a ação que você quer dentro do `handler` do "Aceito". Por exemplo, para navegar para a HomePage, você pode incluir `this.navCtrl.push("HomePage");`.

```
function showConfirm() {
    const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Deseja Realmente Sair ?',
        message: 'Você será redirecionado para a PáginaPrincipal',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Não Aceito',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Disagree clicked');
                }
            },
            {
               text: 'Aceito',
               handler: () => {
                  console.log('Agree clicked');
                  this.navCtrl.push("HomePage");
               }
           }
       ]
   });
   confirm.present();
}
```